# Incrementing operation in VTL

Tags: velocity, vtl

I am trying to use the substring method in VTL as mentioned below

```
#set ($Score = $row.getValue("Score").substring(0,$row.getValue("Score").length()-1))
```

but it says

```
    Encountered "-1" at 
Was expecting one of:
   "," ...
   ")" ...
   <WHITESPACE> ...
   <DOT> ...
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks
Kishore

Comment: By VTL, do you mean Velocity?

Comment: yes Velocity Template Language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#set( $value = $row.getValue("Score") )
#set( $len = $value.length() - 1 )
#set( $Score = $value.substring(0, $len))
```

or, if you are using VelocityTools, you can do this ugly thing:

```
#set( $Score = $row.getValue("Score").substring(0, $math.sub($row.getValue("Score").length(), 1) )
```